# Generate a Complete List of Parent-Child IDs in Single Column Using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have seen numerous examples on this, but none do exactly what I need...and I am having a hard time figuring it out.  (all the examples I see list the results in 2 columns...I don't need that)

I have a table named 'Documents' with 2 columns

- Id
- ParentId (nullable)

Like so...

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Document](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ParentId] [int] NULL
)
```

Populated as such...

```
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] SELECT 1, NULL;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] SELECT 2, 1;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] SELECT 3, 2;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] SELECT 4, NULL;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] SELECT 5, 4;
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Document] SELECT 6, NULL;
```

I need to recursively traverse the parent-child relationship (until NULL) & get a list of all the Id's into a single column, like so...

[image]

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(I assume based on syntax that you are using SQL Server.)

You can use a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
      select id, parentid, 1 as lev
      from document d
      where id = 3
      union all
      select d.id, d.parentid, lev + 1
      from cte join
           document d
           on cte.parentid = d.id
     )
select id
from cte
order by lev;
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/6851f/3) is a SQL Fiddle.

Note:  You cannot insert (normally) into a column declared as `identity`.  If you want to put in the values, remove the `identity()` attribute.

Comment: @PrisonerZERO . . . I also fixed a problem or two with the query (such as `parent_id` versus `parentid` and added a SQL Fiddle.

Comment: Works great...after looking at it...it makes total sense..  Thanks

Comment: @PrisonerZERO . . . I'm impressed.  It took me more than a couple of times to get the hand of so-called recursive queries (they are actually not "recursive" they are inductive, but that is a different matter).